# Convert mail body to UTF-8

Tags: php, email, encoding

I have string `"test+=EC=B9=E8=F8=BE=FD=E1=ED=E9+test"`, it is an email body retrieved using `imap_fetchbody()`. I want to convert it to proper UTF-8 string `"test+ěščřžýáíé+test"`.
I have tried functions `imap_utf7_decode`, `imap_8bit`, `base64_decode`, `quoted_printable_decode` with no success. Can you please advise me a function which will convert mentioned string to UTF-8?

I am using `iconv_mime_decode($str, 0, "UTF-8");` for mail headers, but it does not work for mail body.

Thank you

**The answer is in the accepted answer's comments!**

Comment: What is the character-encoding of the original string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input string appears to be ISO-8859-2, so you can use this function I have adapted from the comments in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php).

```
function decode_qprint($str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/\=([A-F][A-F0-9])/", "%$1", $str);
    $str = urldecode($str);
    $str = iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8", $str);
    return $str;
}
```

**Edit:** Updated function per the comments:

```
function decode_qprint($str) {
    $str = quoted_printable_decode($str);
    $str = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this strips the `+`. And `urldecode()` does not seem like a right way how to treat email text. (But after time I spent with this encoding issue I am not surprised by anything)

Comment: @Andrew123321 Ah sorry, that's what I thought you were after. In that case it's even easier: `$str = quoted_printable_decode($str); $str = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', $str);`

Comment: spencercw: Wow, simple, I am kind of ashamed that I didn't figured this it out myself. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Bear in mind you might need to do something a bit more sophisticated if the emails you are receiving will not always be in ISO-8859-2.

Comment: I see. I have found function `fetchstructure` which has `encoding` as one of parameters of returned object. Possible values are - according to documentation - `7BIT`, `8BIT`, `BINARY`, `BASE64`, `QUOTED-PRINTABLE`, `OTHER`. How can I tell from these what conversion should I use?

Comment: Those aren't granular enough to be able to make a decision on. Look for a character encoding specification in the email headers. Just picking a random email from my inbox I see this: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks again. I have reached it through `$struct = imap_fetchstructure(...); $struct->parts[0]->parameters[0]->value` (parametr `attribute` was "CHARSET"). I hope this is universal.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and your script solved it indeed, but only if I put UTF8 to UTF8 which is non-sense to me but proved to be the only solution: `function decode_qprint($str) {
    $str = quoted_printable_decode($str);
    $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', $str);
    return $str;
}` FYI: I had hungarian characters áéíűőüö diyplayed as =B9=E8=F8 etc.